# java BufferedOutputStream write slow on SSD compared with dd

Tags: java, io, solid-state-drive

> test env:

macbook pro, 2015 early

> dd result:

```
sudo time dd if=/dev/zero of=~/test bs=8k count=500000
500000+0 records in
500000+0 records out
4096000000 bytes transferred in 5.409609 secs (757171197 bytes/sec)
    5.42 real         0.13 user         4.33 sys
```

which is about 757Mb/s

> java code:

```
try {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream("temp_9999"), 8 * 1024);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
        bos.write(0);
    }

    bos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> iostat result during the execution of beyond java code:

```
      disk0           disk2       cpu     load average
  KB/t tps  MB/s     KB/t tps  MB/s  us sy id   1m   5m   15m
  350.48  95 32.45     0.00   0  0.00  39 12 49  2.34 2.59 2.68
  281.13 123 33.88     0.00   0  0.00  42 13 45  2.34 2.59 2.68
  882.42  38 32.63     0.00   0  0.00  36  9 55  2.39 2.59 2.68
  493.16  69 33.21     0.00   0  0.00  36  9 55  2.39 2.59 2.68
```

which is significantly slower than dd, i wonder why BufferedOutputStream is so slow, and how could i improve java write performance?

Comment: Have you tried writing a whole byte array instead of one byte at a time? You seem to be wasting a lot of CPU on this operation.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you're right, i've tried writing a byte[8 * 1024] one time and the throughput increases to about 900Mb/s, but my real input is longs, maybe i should build buffer myself instead of using BufferedOutputStream

Comment: Perhaps you should look into Channels and ByteBuffers (which can easily be used as LongBuffers).